# Header Text does not change after 'References' anymore

Tags: table-of-contents, natbib, appendix

I have a large document for which I use `fancyhdr` to include the heading of the respective section.
I have two questions:

1) Is it possible to only display the heading of the main respective section? So within a subsection, also just display the heading of the overall section?

2) I have changed some code to include my *References* and *Appendix* in the toc without any numbers in front. This worked well, however now my whole Appendix has *References* displayed in the header as shown in the picture. How can I avoid this? I will display a MWE of my code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength\headheight{14pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
% \usepackage[
% backend=biber,
% style=apa,
% sorting=ynt
% ]{biblatex}
% \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
% \addbibresource{Bib.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}

\section{Text}
Text \citep{Almer2017}

\bibliography{Bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
\pagebreak

\section*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Citation example:

```
@article{Almer2017,
    Author = {Christian Almer and Ralph Winkler},
    Journal = {Journal of Environmental Economics and Management},
    Pages = {125-151},
    Title = {{Analyzing the effectiveness of international environmental policies: The case of the Kyoto Protocol}},
    Volume = {82},
    Year = {2017}}
```

Comment: Section* does not write to the header. Try adding `\markboth{Appendix}{Appendix} `

Comment: @daleif Thank you, that worked!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most classes `\section*` does not write to the toc nor the headers/Footers. You'll have to add it manual.

```
\markboth{Appendix}{Appendix}
```